# Extract forename if the character is more then 2 letter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have to get the forename from the `c.forename` if `c.known_as` column is null or blank.
This i achieved with case when statement using

```
CASE 
   WHEN IND.KNOWN_AS IS NULL OR ind.KNOWN_AS='' 
    THEN ind.FORENAMES 
   ELSE ind.KNOWN_AS 
END AS 'Known As'
```

My issue is in the forename column i have name like Jhon Smith where i would like to extract only John, below is an example what i want to achieve

```
Desire output   c.forename
John             Mr John
Jhon            Jhon Smith
blank            Jo
blank              J
```

So , basically it will only take forname skipping 'Mr', 2nd it should take only forename which has more than 2 character.

My current query is:

```
 Select ind.FORENAMES,
        ind.KNOWN_AS,
        case when (known_as is null or known_as = '' ) and charindex(' ', forenames) > 2 
          then substring(forenames, 1, charindex(' ', forenames) - 1) end as FORENAMES2,
        output 
from individual ind 
join member m on m.individual_ref=ind.individual_ref 
  and m.MEMBERSHIP_NO in ('001','002','003','004','005','006','007') 
where m.member_status=33
```

Comment: SQL is not really suited for this type of processing.

Comment: Whence is the source of the string `Smith`?  To me, it's coming out of nowhere.

Comment: Charindex would work here, but still breaks for users with short names. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @OwlsSleeping We have a table which has column like , Known_as, Forename,SurName.  We want to bring everyone  but known_as field shouldnt be blank, if its blank replace it with the value from forename column. but the condition is take the value from the forename column if the character is more than 1 character and take only the first word eg John Smith = Jhon

Comment: What would be your desired output for `Jo Smith`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use following `case when` statement to verify your conditions:

For SQL Server:

```
case when (c.known_as is null or c.known_as = '' )
      and charindex(' ', c.forename) > 3 then substring(c.forename, 1, charindex(' ', c.forename) - 1) end
```

For MySQL:

```
case when (c.known_as is null or c.known_as = '' )
      and locate(' ', c.forename) > 3 then substring(c.forename, 1, locate(' ', c.forename) - 1) end
```

Little explanation: if the first name must be longer than 2 characters, that means that first space must occur at least at index 4. And that what the condition is about: `locate(' ', c.forename) > 3` or `substring(' ', c.forename) > 3`

**NOTE**

You have to first strip down all occurences of `Mr`, `Mrs`, `Ms` in `c.forename` column, like this (syntax for MySQL and SQL Server):

```
replace(replace(replace(c.forename, 'Mrs ', ''),  'Mr ', ''), 'Ms ', '')
```

You have to include it in your query lke this:

```
Select FORENAMES,
       KNOWN_AS,
       case when (known_as is null or known_as = '' ) and charindex(' ', FORENAMES2) > 2 
         then substring(FORENAMES2, 1, charindex(' ', FORENAMES2) - 1) end as FORENAMES2,
       output
from (
    Select ind.FORENAMES,
           ind.KNOWN_AS,
           replace(replace(replace(ind.FORENAMES, 'Mrs ', ''),  'Mr ', ''), 'Ms ', '') FORENAMES2,
           output
    from individual ind 
    join member m on m.individual_ref = ind.individual_ref 
    where m.member_status=33
      and m.MEMBERSHIP_NO in ('001','002','003','004','005','006','007')
)
```

Comment: This will get very ugly, very fast (no criticism of the answer, more of the data). What other titles can be present, Dr? Drs? Ig? Prof? Miss? etc etc etc. And what if initials are also included, what to do with initials MR? This is a minefield.

Comment: @HoneyBadger It is almost impossible to inlucde all this considerations in SQL... but you are completely right and let OP decide, if my efforts help him and solve his problwm :) I based my answer on presented data :)

Comment: @MichałTurczyn it didnt worked brother, returning  NULL for Mr John

Comment: @Biswa You have to also apply inner queary with `REPLACE` as I mentioned

Comment: @MichałTurczyn  here is the query Select ind.FORENAMES,ind.KNOWN_AS,case when (known_as is null or known_as = '' )
      and charindex(' ', forenames) > 2 then substring(forenames, 1, charindex(' ', forenames) - 1) end as Michal_turczyn output

   from individual ind
join member m on m.individual_ref=ind.individual_ref and m.MEMBERSHIP_NO in ('001','002','003','004','005','006','007')
where m.member_status=33   , with this im not getting the person names only John, its return as null

Comment: I solved it using else forename and adding len(forename)>'1' in where clause

Comment: @Biswa "len(forename)>'1' in where clause" doesn't match your sample data. 
That will result in a skipped row in the case where forename='J' rather than a blank result. Sure it's what you want?

Comment: @OwlsSleeping Yes dear friend. I wanted to skip that record as i dont want known as to be updated as J. But now we are not going to use the script to get correct data but we will do some data cleansing activity to correct those known as field. so that the known as column is populated with correct records. Thanks for your help, it was really helpful my friend.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [name] VARCHAR(32)
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([name])
VALUES (' Mr John ')
      ,('Jhon Smith')
      ,('  Jo  ')
      ,('  J  ');

WITH SanitizeDataSoruce ([name], [name_reversed]) AS
(
    SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM([name]))
          ,REVERSE(LTRIM(RTRIM([name])))
    FROM @DataSource
)
SELECT [name]
      ,CASE 
            WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', [name]) > 1 THEN REVERSE(SUBSTRING([name_reversed], 0, CHARINDEX(' ', [name_reversed])))
            ELSE ''
       END
FROM SanitizeDataSoruce;
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @gotqn it works like a charm, but the problem is i have a data set which has 30000 rows. and i need to return known as for 30000 , in some case we have known_as populated. i only need to case statement to change known as with forename with the criteria when the known_as column is null

Comment: @Biswa Then instead `ELSE ''` use `ELSE known_as`? Or even better - check if know_as is NULL, if yes, calculated it, if not, return it.

Comment: I solved it using else forename and adding  len(forename)>'1' in where clause.